# How to load function on web application startup in openshift

Tags: java, php, openshift

here is what I want to do:
I want to make an 'executable-like' application running on a web server, with a doSomething() function. On web application startup, the doSomething() function connects as a client to another MQTT server through web sockets, subscribes there, and stores the incoming messages to a database. I don't care about the content of the doSomethihg() function. I can do this. I am only interested in making a deamon app in a web server.
This application will run either in glassfish (java) or apache (php).
I will deploy this application in openshift o another similar PAAS, so it must be a web app, no a standalone one. Plus, I suppose I don't have the ability to execute shell scripts.
I only found a way to do this with java; Make a servlet and configure it to run at application startup (use load-on-startup in web.xml file). I don't know if this is the most efficient, and I didn't find anything for php. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly **is** your question? Whether a service that can create daemons exists for PHP? If so, a simple Google search would have revealed sites such as https://daemon.io/. If not, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also be sure to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: What I want to do is have an application running on a web server, apache or glassfish, without user interaction. The application will be deployed on openshift. I did nothing yet to solve the problem, as it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have an 'application startup' per se, but it sounds like you may want [a cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). You can create a cron job to run every so many minutes, and it will launch its function without any user interaction. Setting a conditional flag in a cron job would ensure that the code only ever runs once.

Alternatively, you can execute a function whenever a particular page is loaded by a visitor. This function could set a flag (as a `$_SESSION` variable) that checks whether or not the function has already run:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['done'])) {
    doSomething();
}


function doSomething() {
    // Do something
    $_SESSION['done'] = 'yes';
}

?>
```

That way you can get the function to trigger once per visitor if need be.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! The crone way soundes interesting. I will check if this is supported  by openShift and give it a try. Any thoughts for java/glassfish?